# How to do client-side remote validation without submiting the form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I actually have a MVC.Net form using a viewmodel with a field having `Required` and `Remote` attributes. The client-side validation works pretty-well for the `Required` part... but not as I expect for the `Remote`.

The problem is I can't make the `Remote` validation until the form has been validated once :

- The Name field is filled with an existing username - no error is shown, as there is no call made to the server
- I validate the form, an ajax call is made to check the username validity, and an error message is shown
- Now, everytime I type something in the username field, an ajax call is made and the error message is updated accordingly

Here is the model :

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")]
    [MinLength(3)]
    [Remote("CheckUserName", "CSValidationTest")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The view :

```
@model TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

And the controller :

```
public class CSValidationTestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult CheckUserName(string userName)
    {
        bool result = new Random().Next() > Int32.MaxValue / 2;

        if (result)
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json("Username already used, guid for call unicity : " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Also, I can't remove the `Required` attribute because javascript can be disabled or tweaked, and using `ModelState.IsValid` is pretty convenient.

Is there a way to call the remote rule before the first submit ?

Comment: Use JQuery Validation function for that if require I will share you the code.

Comment: @LaxmanGite What do you mean by "JQuery Validation function" ?

Comment: Try this type of code on any event before submitting the form : function isvalid() { if ($("#DrpTest option:selected").val() == "") {return "<p>Please select Test." + "</p>\n"; } else { return ""; } }

Comment: I don't see how this could help me with my remote validation.

Comment: Remote validation is working while you are typing in the text right?

Comment: Its not clear what you want the behavior to be. By default, jquery validation is 'lazy'. An element is only validated when its changed, and thereafter on `keyup`

Comment: @User3250 Remote validation works only after I tried to submit the form once. Before that, nothing happens, and I don't see any request in the network console. But after that first submit, yes, the remote validation is made at every key stroke.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The remote validation isn't working until I try to validate the form once. Then, the validation is made in ajax, and the submit is blocked if the validation fail.

Comment: It wont validate until you change the value, or until the form is submitted (that's the default behavior), but the value should obviously be valid if you have passed it to the view so I'm not sure I understand what your wanting. Its also not clear what your `CheckUserName()` is doing - you pass a value for `userName` but never use it, and you do not seem to be doing any check if it exists (and if you did you would need to pass another value to indicate if you editing an existing user or creating a new user)

Comment: @StephenMuecke the controller content is for testing purpose only, `CheckUserName()` is actually doing more than just a random. What I want is the remote validation to work before I submit the form - in my tests, if I change the value of the field BEFORE I try to submit the form, no remote validation occur.

Comment: If you change the value in the control, it will call your `CheckUserName()` method (but the parameter needs to match the property name - i.e. `CheckUserName(string name)`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled, this two in **`webconfig`** file.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Comment: As I wrote, "The client-side validation works pretty-well for the Required part". The client-side validation works well, I actually want to change its behavior :)

Comment: You have given MinLength as 3, once the name value reaches minlength  for every keypress request is going to CheckUserName() method.